# ORDER BY a certain sequence in a fetch array

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a query that I am using for labels in a bar graph. I am extracting those labels using fetch_array in PHP. The label order should be:

White, African American, Hispanic etc etc.

but once we do any type order by asc or desc they come in alphabetical order such as

African American, Hispanic, White. Is there a way to order these specifically in a certain order?

Comment: You can reorder those labels in PHP, once you got it from mysql

Comment: @NishuTayal yes, but to do that he should use string matching, easy to break the code if a label changes or number of labels changes. Other option would be match the label ID's, not so practical, but it's my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement to specify your sort order.  It will assign 0 to the value `White` and 1 to all other values, then sort the remaining values alphabetically.

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN label='White' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  label ASC
```

Comment: Does it not slow down the query? I'm not sure but seems inefficient, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Cranio It is a common practice and the performance impact is likely to be minimal especially if the column has an index.

Answer (score 0):

You should define an order elsewhere (as your order is freeform you cannot rely on automatic solutions).
One trick could be adding an `myorder` field in your table, so you can specify `ORDER BY myorder` in your query:

```
 id  desc      myorder
 ..  ......... ..........
 1   Hispanic  3
 2   White     2
 3   African-  1
```

One advantage of this approach is that it is reusable, you can edit the order software-wise (if you need this particular kind of option) and works for an arbitrary number of rows.

Comment: This is ideal but I do not have access to edit the db. But, I do agree logically right.

Answer (score -2):

in mysql you can use the [field function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) for custom sort order. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM GraphTable ORDER BY FIELD(GraphLabel, 'White', 'African American', 'Hispanic')
```

Or by id:

```
SELECT * FROM GraphTable ORDER BY FIELD(LabelID, 123, 456, 234);
```

From the mysql manual:

> FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)
>
> Returns the index (position) of str in the str1, str2, str3, ... list. Returns 0 if str is not found.

Comment: Not good for arbitrary number of labels, editing and reusability.

Comment: @Cranio How is this any different than using a case, I can do `ORDER BY FIELD(Label, 'White') DESC, Label ASC` and get the exact same results as the case statement in less.

Comment: Maybe because FIELD has to be evaluated every time. In addition, if one wants to implement a way to change the label order, you should change the query every time